# Add new list field to object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, list

I'm struggling to add(convert json to list of jsons) list to json. Here is the example:

```
config = {
  existing_variable: 'example'
}


addToListing = (field, value, index=0) => {
  config = {
    ...config,
    listing: {   
      ...config.listing,
      [field]: value
    }   
  }
}

addToListing('first', 1, 0)
addToListing('second', 2, 0)
addToListing('first', 3, 1)


console.log(config)
```

Result:

```
{
  existing_variable: 'example', 
  listing: 
  { 
    first: 3, 
    second: 2 
  } 
}
```

Expected result:

```
{ 
  existing_variable: 'example', 
  listing: 
  [
    {first: 1, second: 2}, 
    {first: 3}
  ] 
}
```

I've tried different approaches, but what I did wasn't suitable(e.g nested values or complete initialization at beggining).

Could you please help?

Comment: what is a list of [JSON](https://json.org/)?

Comment: I'm new to JS, you are both right this is object, not JSON. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add some checks and rewind the array.

```js
const addToListing = (field, value, index=0) => {
    config = {
        ...config,
        listing: Object.assign(
            [],
            (config.listing || []), 
            { [index]: { ...(config.listing?.[index] || []), [field]: value } }
        )    
    }
};

var config = { existing_variable: 'example' };

addToListing('first', 1, 0);
addToListing('second', 2, 0);
addToListing('first', 3, 1);

console.log(config)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Without [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) but with more default values.

```js
const addToListing = (field, value, index=0) => {
    config = {
        ...config,
        listing: Object.assign(
            [],
            (config.listing || []), 
            { [index]: { ...((config.listing || [])[index] || []), [field]: value } }
        )    
    }
};

var config = { existing_variable: 'example' };

addToListing('first', 1, 0);
addToListing('second', 2, 0);
addToListing('first', 3, 1);

console.log(config)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It works, but unfortunately I cannot use optional chaining :/

Answer (score 0):

I am proposing an alternative approach using [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```js
let config = {
  existing_variable: 'example'
}


const addToListing = (field, value, index = 0) => {
 // If listing property not exists then init it with an empty array
 config.listing || (config.listing = [])
 
 config.listing.splice(index, 1, (config.listing[index] ? {...config.listing[index], [field]: value} : {[field]: value}));
}

addToListing('first', 1, 0)
addToListing('second', 2, 0)
addToListing('first', 3, 1)


console.log(config);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

Comment: Actually there should be 2 objects(first two values in first object, and third value in second object) in this array instead of 3.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvinience. I've updated my answer. Please have a look.